# GitlabCI pipeline run only with code from master

Tags: gitlab-ci

I need to run pipeline everytime there is a commit on non-master branch. The pipeline starts but the code is from master. I need the code from the changed branch

Pipeline is like this:

```
variables:
  IMAGE_TAG: ${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
  BASE_NAME: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}

stages:
  - validate
  - build

check_image:
  stage: validate
  tags:
    - runner
  script:
    - cd ~/path/${BASE_NAME}-base && packer validate ${BASE_NAME}-base.json
  except: ['master']

create_image:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - runner
  script:
    - cd ~/path/${BASE_NAME}-base && packer build -force ${BASE_NAME}-base.json
  except: ['master']
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out. I was running gitlab-runner under custom user so the environment is already set. I just have to add before_script to checkout the desired branch.